# Editing the exe program in jetbrains rider avalonia

Tags: exe

I am absolutely zero in programming. But I know some things that I need to do. And so. I have a program written in AVALONIA. I downloaded JetBrains Rider, downloaded the avalonia module. I log into the program, add my own software. In the software, I change the part of the code that I need. How do I save the program back so that the changes are recorded?
The program is written in net 6. I add the net executable configuration (I do not know whether it is correct or not).

I specify access to the file. I press start. In the console, it enters (No loaded projects
CONSOLE: Use build tool: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
MSBuild version 17.9.5+33de0b227 for .NET Framework
MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify the project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or a solution file.) But the program starts later, but there are no changes that I made.